# Rearrange table in Excel

Tags: excel

In Excel, I need to convert entries like this one:

```
+------------+-------------------+--------+
|    Date    |      Details      | Amount |
+------------+-------------------+--------+
| 15/02/2016 | Payment type      |  37.42 |
+------------+-------------------+--------+
|            | Payment details 1 |        |
+------------+-------------------+--------+
|            | Payment details 2 |        |
+------------+-------------------+--------+
|            | Payment details 3 |        |
+------------+-------------------+--------+
```

To this:

```
+------------+--------------+--------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|    Date    |   Details    | Amount |                   |                   |                   |
+------------+--------------+--------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 15/02/2016 | Payment type |  37.42 | Payment details 1 | Payment details 2 | Payment details 3 |
+------------+--------------+--------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Long story short, left-side orphan rows should be added to the right of the parent row, each as a new column.

How can I do it in a easy way?

Comment: It depends, do you consider VBA easy?

Comment: I did it a while ago using Perl and the CSV version of the file. But it takes time, preparations, conversions, etc. So I guess there's no other way than writing a macro?

Comment: is it always in the same format with 3 payment details and then repeat?

Comment: The number of orphan rows might change. Otherwise it's the same pattern.

Comment: Seems like in any specific case you could do it yourself with a simple cut followed by paste-special (which includes a transpose option). Perhaps that is what you are looking for. Automating it would require VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to write it myself, I just need to test some more, to make sure everything is ok:

```
Option Explicit
Sub move_details()
Dim i As Long
Dim notEmpty As Long
Dim wantedRow As Long
Dim offset As Long
Dim a As Variant
offset = 6
notEmpty = 2
wantedRow = 3
For i = 1 To Rows.Count
If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
    a = Cells(i, wantedRow).Value
    Cells(notEmpty, offset).Value = a
    offset = offset + 1
    Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    i = i - 1
Else
    offset = 6
    notEmpty = i
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub move_details()
Dim rw, last_rw, offset, cl As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
rw = 1
cl = 4
While Cells(rw, 2) <> ""
    If Trim(Cells(rw, 1)) = "" Then
        Cells(rw - 1, cl) = Cells(rw, 2)
        Rows(rw).Delete
        cl = cl + 1
    Else
        rw = rw + 1
        cl = 4
    End If
Wend

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: I receive a Runtime Error 1004: “Application-defined or object-defined error.”. But I might be doing something wrong, maybe not using the macro correctly. I don't have much experience with macros. It doesn't like this line: `Cells(rw - 1, cl) = Cells(rw, 2)`